# Code Igniter Get Comments Count from another table For Post List Array for API response

Tags: mysql, api, codeigniter, count, response

**Hello,**

I am working on a Posts and Comment Models response API in Code Igniter!

MY Controller:

```
    public function getPosts()
  {
    if (isset($_POST["getPosts"]))
    {
      $data = $this->api_model->getPosts();
      $json_response2 = array('status' => 'success', 'postList' => $data->result_array());
      echo json_encode($json_response2);
    }
    else
    {
      $data['status'] = 'error';
      echo json_encode($data);
    }
  }
```

My Model:

```
public function get_posts()
    {
            $this->db->order_by('postID', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();
    }
```

MYSQL Tables:

```
for Posts---
postID | postTitle | postBody

for Comments---
commentID | postID | commentBody
```

I want to Get Comments Count for post Array in API response to display list of posts and comments Count for that Post?

ThankYou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query needed for you to get all those data in single query. It will join both table with left join clause and will give you the comment count as well.

```
SELECT 
  p.`postID`,
  `postTitle`,
  `postBody`,
  COUNT(c.commentID) AS comment_cnt
FROM
  `Posts` AS p 
  LEFT JOIN `Comments` AS c 
    ON p.postID = c.postID 
GROUP BY c.postID 
ORDER BY p.postID DESC ;
```

> N:B left join is mandatory, otherwise it will not give you zero
>   commented post.

to convert it to codeigniter you can write it as.

```
$this->db->from('Posts p');
$this->db->join('Comments c','p.postID = c.postID','left');
$this->db->group_by('c.postID');
$this->db->order_by('p.postID', 'DESC');
$this->db->select('p.*,COUNT(c.commentID) AS comment_cnt');
$query = $this->db->get();

$res = $query->result_array();
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Could You help to join a user data to that post array like 

 $this->db->join('users','posts.postID = users.userID'');


i want get user names who posted with that posts array

Comment: in your question you aren't mentioned anything about userdata. "postID | postTitle | postBody"

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your **comments** table to get count and group by your postID.
Modify your `get_posts()` function in model as follows:

```
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->select("posts.*, count(*) as comments_count");
$this->db->join('comments', 'posts.postID = comments.postID');
$this->db->group_by('posts.postID');
$this->db->order_by('postID', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Also, you are using result_array() twice which is wrong. Change your controller line

```
      $json_response2 = array('status' => 'success', 'postList' => $data->result_array());
```

as

```
      $json_response2 = array('status' => 'success', 'postList' => $data);
```

because you are already getting result from model.

Also, use the correct name for function in controller, `$this->api_model->get_posts();`

Hope it helps.

Comment: this solution will not return a post which doesn't have a comment in comment table

Comment: Yes, But i need the posts those who does not have comments too, with a comment count value '0'